# Magento 2.3 Fatal error: '\self' is an invalid class name

Tags: magento2.3, fatal-error, php-7.2

I'm getting the following error on **Magento 2.3**:

> Fatal error: '\self' is an invalid class name in
>   /private/var/www/xxx/generated/code/Magento/Indexer/Model/Indexer/DependencyDecorator/Interceptor.php
>   on line 137

Didn't find so much info on this after googling, except for this, but it seems to be unresolved. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11905

**PHP 7.2.10**

Anyone ideas on what the issue is?

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator;
/**
 * Interceptor class for @see \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator
 */
class Interceptor extends \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator implements \Magento\Framework\Interception\InterceptorInterface
{
    use \Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterface $indexer, \Magento\Framework\Indexer\Config\DependencyInfoProviderInterface $dependencyInfoProvider, \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry)
{
    $this->___init();
    parent::__construct($indexer, $dependencyInfoProvider, $indexerRegistry);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function __call(string $method, array $args)
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, '__call');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::__call($method, $args);
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('__call', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getId() : string
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getId');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::getId();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('getId', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getViewId() : string
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getViewId');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::getViewId();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('getViewId', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getActionClass() : string
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getActionClass');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::getActionClass();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('getActionClass', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getTitle() : string
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getTitle');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::getTitle();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('getTitle', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getDescription() : string
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getDescription');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::getDescription();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('getDescription', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getFields() : array
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getFields');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::getFields();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('getFields', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getSources() : array
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getSources');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::getSources();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('getSources', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getHandlers() : array
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getHandlers');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::getHandlers();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('getHandlers', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function load($indexerId) : \self
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'load');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::load($indexerId);
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('load', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getView() : \Magento\Framework\Mview\ViewInterface
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getView');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::getView();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('getView', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getState() : \Magento\Framework\Indexer\StateInterface
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getState');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::getState();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('getState', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setState(\Magento\Framework\Indexer\StateInterface $state) : \self
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'setState');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::setState($state);
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('setState', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isScheduled() : bool
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'isScheduled');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::isScheduled();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('isScheduled', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setScheduled($scheduled)
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'setScheduled');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::setScheduled($scheduled);
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('setScheduled', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isValid() : bool
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'isValid');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::isValid();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('isValid', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isInvalid() : bool
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'isInvalid');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::isInvalid();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('isInvalid', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isWorking() : bool
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'isWorking');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::isWorking();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('isWorking', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function invalidate()
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'invalidate');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::invalidate();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('invalidate', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getStatus() : string
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getStatus');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::getStatus();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('getStatus', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getLatestUpdated() : string
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getLatestUpdated');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::getLatestUpdated();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('getLatestUpdated', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function reindexAll()
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'reindexAll');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::reindexAll();
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('reindexAll', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function reindexRow($id)
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'reindexRow');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::reindexRow($id);
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('reindexRow', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function reindexList($ids)
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'reindexList');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::reindexList($ids);
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('reindexList', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please share code of your file.